# Kotlin Coroutines with Node Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin, node-modules, kotlin-coroutines

I'm asking myself how I can use Kotlin's coroutines together with some node modules.
I'm trying to write a node.js server in Kotlin.

It would be simple to keep using JavaScripts famous callbacks or maybe Promises,
but it looks like Kotlin callbacks would be the better option.
However for a node.js server I need to use MySQL or bcrypt libraries only working with callbacks or Promises but not with coroutines because it is not written in Kotlin respectively.

The Kotlin documentation does not help me, JetBrains says I only need to write my method like it is working synchronously and use other Kotlin functions just like they were running synchronously, but the functions written in native JavaScript do not know a keyword like "suspend", or should I just ignore this fact?

An example would be following function:

```
val bcrypt = require("bcrypt") // require by node.js
fun comparePass(hash: String, pass: String, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, { err: dynamic, res: dynamic ->
        callback(err == null)
    })
}
```

How can I write this function using coroutines and this libary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the documentation wanted you to write:

```
suspend fun comparePass(hash: String, pass: String): Boolean =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        bcrypt.compare(pass, hash) { err: dynamic, res: dynamic ->
            continuation.resume(err == null)
        }
    }
```

Note that your own callback is now replaced with the `Continuation`, which is the internal callback that allows the coroutine to resume. Note also that the return value of your `comparePass` function is now simply `Boolean` and you call it like a regular function, passing no callbacks of your own.

I don't have first-hand experience with Kotlin-JS, I don't know the semantics of that `dynamic` type, so I can't know whether this will work.